# bash script to restart the service if dead and write a log into debug.log

Tags: wordpress, bash, restart

I have a script (copied from another blog) to restart the service when it's dead as below.

```
#!/bin/bash
 
SERVICE="sshd"
STATUS="$(systemctl is-active $SERVICE)"
 
if [ "$STATUS" != "active" ]; then
    echo "Service $SERVICE is not running"
    systemctl restart $SERVICE
    echo "Service $SERVICE has been restarted"
    # Send notification here
else
    echo "Service $SERVICE is running"
fi
```

Is it possible to add a function to write a log (i.g. Service $SERVICE has been restarted) into debug.log that is located under /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/ ?

Please help.

Comment: just FYI, in case this is a publicly facing website, make sure you block all access to the `debug.log` file - maybe using .htaccess

Comment: `echo "Service $SERVICE has been restarted" >> /path/to/wp-content/debug.log`

Comment: You can just append directly to the log file.  Or you can use the `logger` command to write messages to the system log, which can be combined with syslog configuration to control where those messages go.

Comment: `man systemd` ?

Comment: Why not just let `systemd` restart the service automatically? That also takes care of the logging, of all dependencies that could potentially prevent the service from running etc. Homebrew hacks are always unreliable and bound to fail.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek Are you saying the current code will do the logging automatically? May I know where it writes the log as default then?

Comment: @JohnBollinger What do I need to add in order to write the message to the system log? and what is the path to the log in default?

Comment: @Cornel Raiu I am learning. If I code to write the log into debug.log, does it mean debug.log will be exposed to public?

Comment: `systemd` it's job is to facilitate executing long running services, including handling execution and restarting.

Comment: @futureyoon yes. You can check by going incognito and trying to access `domain.com/wp-content/debug.log`.

Comment: @futureyoon `journalctl` is great to know. Where the (binary) log files are stored is quite irrelevant, somewhere under `/var`, documentation has it. The very purpose of `systemd` and its logger (`systemd-journald`) is to get rid of homebrew logging in favor of a centralized, reliable logging facility with proper log rotation etc. So yes, of course `systemd` will log (also) your job’s restarts.

Comment: Did you try the #silver comment?